# How magnetic filed lines become concentrated in the center of solenoid?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Are the magnetic field lines concentrated in the center of a solenoid or the magnetic field will be uniform inside the solenoid?[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the limiting case of an infinitely long solenoid, the field (hence field lines) will be uniformly distributed.

Shorter solenoids have ends, and the field spreads out past the ends, and also spreads out in the end parts of the solenoid.

As the ends get closer, this “end effect” gets bigger. That image looks about right for a solenoid that short.

The other limit is just one turn of wire, where the field isn’t uniform at all.